# call phtml file in cms page magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to call a phtml file in a CMS page in magento 1.9:

```
phtml file path: frontend/base/default/template/inchoo/search
```

I have created a new cms page in admin and under content wrote this:

```
{{block type="inchoo/search" name="mycstompage" template="inchoo/search/form.phtml"}}
```

cleared cache

But when I refresh page it shows nothing. Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can yo please add the complete content of your CMS page, at least a few lines above and below the {{block}}